# Why doesn't it work when I use the same variable for 'x' and 'fill' aesthetic in geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Riddle me this: When I use the same variable as `x` and `fill` aesthetic for a `geom_bar` (I know that this is redundant coding), the `fill` mapping is not used.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(Points=c(1, 3, rep(5,20), rep(20,80), rep(40,35), rep(70,22), rep(100,18)))
ggplot(df, aes(fill = Points, x = Points)) +
  geom_bar(width=.1) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1,3,5,10,20,40,70,100))
```

[image]

What's happening?!? I suspect it must have to do something with the inner workings of `geom_bar` because it's calculating the `..count..` variable for the y-axis. But that shouldn't affect the variable `Points`, no?

One more thing: It **does** work, when I wrap an `as.character()` around `Points` for the `fill` aesthetic. But then I don't get a nice continuous color scale but a discrete color scale (which makes sense for a character variable).

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want a continuous scale for how the bars are filled, the trick is to set y=1, so the bars will stack on top of one another on the respective x positions, then call fill.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Points)) + geom_col(aes(y=1,fill=Points))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry Wolf, what I meant was using Points for both the x-axis and the coloring - not the count.

Comment: To paraphrase: Points should be on the x-axis AND the color fill.

Comment: so you want a color for every frequency, and then you stack the bars?

Comment: I see, so I definitely need `geom_col` for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right about it calculating `..count..`. So why not generate the counts directly and use `geom_col()` instead:

```
df %>%
  count(Points) %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = Points, x = Points, y = n)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(1,3,5,10,20,40,70,100)) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = 'gray', high = 'red')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks AHart, I now see that I need `geom_col` instead of `geom_bar`. I've accepted the earlier answer by StupidWolf.